# mod_fcgid: No space left on device

Tags: apache-2.2, vps, mod-fcgid

I'm having a problem where apache2 won't start at all on my VPS, and it outputs this error:

```
[Mon May 09 07:00:38 2011] [emerg] (28)No space left on device: mod_fcgid: Can't create shared memory for size 13018600 bytes
```

I know for a fact that I have enough memory (I have 2 gb available plus 1 gb burstable).

Any ideas on what it could be?

EDIT:

If it is any help, the VPS is running on OpenVZ and the guest operating system is Ubuntu 10.04 64bit

Answer (score 1):

@dgrimbergen is right. Check this for example: http://blog.forestsoft.de/2011/01/shared-memory-issue-with-mod_fcgid/

If not, is the sharemempath set in your Apache config (httpd.conf or apache2.conf)?

```
SharememPath /var/run/fcgid_shm
```

Make sure this directory exists, is chmod "700" and owned by the same owner as the webserver is running under (www / www-data).

Comment: I'm trying to add SharememPath /var/run/fcgid_shm. I'll post back with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Something is using up all shared memory. As root run:

> ipcs -m

This will give you a list of all shared memory allocations. The second column (shmid) gives you the id of the allocation.

If you want to remove some allocations, you can use:

> ipcrm -m

It would be better to find out why a process is allocation all the memory and take steps against that (or get more memory).

Comment: Absolutely nothing is appearing with ipcs -m. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this occurred because the `/var` filesystem ran out of [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).  This shows an example of a system that is running out of free inodes:

```
$ df -i /var
Filesystem          Inodes  IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cis-var 327680 277671 50009   85% /var
```

Just to be clear, when the inodes run out, the same error will occur as for a filesystem that has run out of free blocks, i.e. "Errno (28)No space left on device".